# how do i add permanent run_list by chef-client

Tags: chef-infra

i know the way of add run_list by knife
but my environment is too strict , so can't connect the client server with network.

`chef-client -o` option can replace the run_list , but it's only once and it's not saving the node's run_list.

is there any idea for add run_list permanently with chef-client option (except -j XXX.json)?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer is No.  If you are using Chef server, there are basically two choices:

- Put your node configuration details into the server (permanently) so that chef-client can fetch them.
- Set the node configuration details (temporarily) via chef-client options or a JSON file.

Anything else would entail using multiple Chef servers, and I don't think that's possible (let alone sensible).

If your environment is so "strict" that you can't update the node configs in the server ... and you really need to do that ... then I think you should consider setting up your own private Chef server, and getting your nodes taken out of the "main" server.

---

This all sounds a bit broken.  Either you are trying to control your machine in ways that "they" don't think you should be able to ... or "they" are not properly aware of what you need to do, and why.  In your position, I'd talk to your line management about it.  Expending a lot of effort to *work around* institutional inflexibility needs management approval, and if you don't get approval you are asking for trouble.  Fighting "the system" could be bad for your ongoing employment ...